# Java web-applications loses JNDI configured DS connection on WLS

Tags: java, spring, maven, datasource, jndi

I have a fairly simple web-application running on WebLogic. It is built using Maven on Spring MVC as a two-tier application, with a front-end module and a core (business) module.

I have a DAO package (with DAO implementation classes) which all utilize a Singleton called JNDIConnector, creating a connection through the JNDI datasource to a DB2 table. The essence of the JNDIConnector is this method:

```
private static Connection getJNDIConnection() {
    String DATASOURCE_CONTEXT = "java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx_ds";

    Connection result = null;
    try {
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
        if( dataSource != null ) {
            result = dataSource.getConnection();
        } else {
            LOG.error( "UNABLE TO LOOKUP DATASOURCE!!!" );
        }
    } catch( NamingException ex ) {
        LOG.error( "Unable to connect through JNDI: " + ex );
    } catch( SQLException ex ) {
        LOG.error( "Caught SQLException: " + ex );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        LOG.error("Caught Exception: " + e );
    }
    return result;
}
```

The connection is only retrieved by the DAO implementations, in case it is null or closed.

The error we are seeing, after the application has run for a few days, is this:

```
2014-11-11 14:51:01 ERROR xxxRepository:389 - Caught SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][3.64.106] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003
```

I have googled this error, and it seemed to be the JDBC driver version causing this error. The driver has been updated, but we still see the error. If we flip the server, the connection works again for a few days.

The application has been tested in three different environments so far: locally, in "development test" and in "acceptance test" environments. The error I have described, is for the acceptance test environment only (so far) - the other two environments works flawlessly. I have googled to my heart's content, and not yet found an answer that would remedy the problem.

I am at a loss for solutions, and our operations team cannot find any errors in the application server log files.

How do I go about this? Is my code solid? Should I do something differently/better/more robust?

//Casper

Comment: You are using Spring but are doing manually lookups for your datasource. Let Spring do the lookup and manage your connections (makes your code even easier testable!) instead of getting your own. Also instead of using the `Connection` directly it is advisable to use a `JdbcTemplate` instead (saves you a lot of messy SQL code).

Comment: Good point, I'll rewrite that right away. However, it still does not explain the error we're experiencing. I'm wondering if some sort of keep-alive could remedy the losing of the connection?

Comment: Make sure that you close the connection properly after use (or preferably let tx management code handle that for you) and that you don't hold a reference to the connection.